# USB Audio Device (Tascam US-2x2HR) sporadically fails to load, making other USB devices inoperable. How can I fix or debug this problem?

Tags: usb-device, usb-audio

I dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS. In Windows, my audio device (Tascam US-2x2HR) works well. In Ubuntu, it does not work on boot, but if I repeatedly unplug it and plug it back in, it will eventually work perfectly. Sometimes, when I plug it in, it seems to partially hang the computer (e.g. I can click on the button to open a terminal) but the terminal does not open until I unplug the audio device.

Here are the best log snippets I know how to find. Happy to provide additional info of course!

Here is a snippet from `dmesg` that seems to have some relevant information.

```
[  425.021608] pcieport 0000:00:03.2: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:03.2
[  425.021622] pcieport 0000:00:03.2: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  425.021626] pcieport 0000:00:03.2:   device [8086:2f0a] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  425.021643] pcieport 0000:00:03.2:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  429.346228] usb 3-3: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-110)
[  434.462227] usb 3-3: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-110)
[  439.610209] usb 3-3: 1:1: cannot get freq (v2/v3): err -110
[  444.730280] usb 3-3: 1:1: cannot set freq 44100 (v2/v3): err -110
[  449.822347] usb 3-3: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-110)
[  454.942400] usb 3-3: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-110)
[  460.090325] usb 3-3: 1:1: cannot get freq (v2/v3): err -110
```

And when I `tail -f /var/log/syslog` this is what happens after I plug in the device and it fails.

```
Nov 14 08:13:32 desktop kernel: [ 1429.572860] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
Nov 14 08:13:32 desktop kernel: [ 1429.721386] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0644, idProduct=8070, bcdDevice= 1.00
Nov 14 08:13:32 desktop kernel: [ 1429.721394] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov 14 08:13:32 desktop kernel: [ 1429.721398] usb 3-3: Product: US-2x2HR
Nov 14 08:13:32 desktop kernel: [ 1429.721401] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: TASCAM
Nov 14 08:13:32 desktop kernel: [ 1429.721404] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: no serial number
Nov 14 08:13:37 desktop kernel: [ 1434.973026] usb 3-3: parse_audio_format_rates_v2v3(): unable to retrieve number of sample rates (clock 1)
Nov 14 08:14:32 desktop systemd-udevd[436]: 3-3: Worker [6354] processing SEQNUM=6118 is taking a long time
Nov 14 08:14:44 desktop mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3"
Nov 14 08:14:44 desktop mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 10 was not an MTP device
Nov 14 08:14:44 desktop mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3"
Nov 14 08:14:44 desktop mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 10 was not an MTP device
Nov 14 08:14:49 desktop kernel: [ 1506.627314] usb 3-3: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-110)
Nov 14 08:14:54 desktop kernel: [ 1511.775449] usb 3-3: 1:1: cannot get freq (v2/v3): err -110
Nov 14 08:14:59 desktop kernel: [ 1516.895577] usb 3-3: 1:1: cannot set freq 44100 (v2/v3): err -110
Nov 14 08:15:04 desktop kernel: [ 1521.987790] usb 3-3: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-110)
Nov 14 08:15:09 desktop kernel: [ 1527.107948] usb 3-3: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-110)
```

Sometimes the device shows up in `lsusb` (even if it is not working properly) and sometimes running lsusb freezes the terminal until I unplug the device (or wait a long time).

And finally, here is the `syslog` content after a succcessful unplug/plug. The device works fine after this.

```
Nov 14 09:30:01 desktop CRON[13126]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Nov 14 09:30:27 desktop kernel: [ 6044.374629] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
Nov 14 09:30:27 desktop kernel: [ 6044.523123] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0644, idProduct=8070, bcdDevice= 1.00
Nov 14 09:30:27 desktop kernel: [ 6044.523134] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov 14 09:30:27 desktop kernel: [ 6044.523138] usb 3-3: Product: US-2x2HR
Nov 14 09:30:27 desktop kernel: [ 6044.523141] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: TASCAM
Nov 14 09:30:27 desktop kernel: [ 6044.523143] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: no serial number
Nov 14 09:30:27 desktop mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 18: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3"
Nov 14 09:30:27 desktop mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 18 was not an MTP device
Nov 14 09:30:27 desktop systemd-udevd[13159]: controlC3: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore 3' failed with exit code 99.
Nov 14 09:30:27 desktop mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 18: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3"
Nov 14 09:30:27 desktop mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 18 was not an MTP device
Nov 14 09:30:29 desktop kernel: [ 6046.861313] retire_capture_urb: 2 callbacks suppressed
Nov 14 09:30:29 desktop gsd-media-keys[2662]: Unable to get default source
Nov 14 09:30:52 desktop systemd[1917]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
Nov 14 09:30:53 desktop systemd[1917]: Started VTE child process 13205 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 3364.
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading about others experiencing the -110 usb error e.g.

```
usb 3-3: 1:0: usb_set_interface failed (-110)
```

I tried to power the computer off, **unplug it** and leave it for five minutes, and reboot the computer. On boot I did not see the issue again. Finger's crossed that is the end of the issue!

Comment: Sadly the issue came back the next day. I think the problem stems from my dual-booting. When I boot into Windows, I think it confounds Linux on next boot.